# Form Subscriber on radio button receive wierd value

Tags: forms, symfony, radio-button, listener

I have a form with a field that should appear only if a previous radio button is checked as "Oui".
To do this, I use a Form Subscriber attached to the radio field.

The Form Type :

```
class RegistrationStep3UserDataType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * RegistrationUserDataType constructor.
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new ActivityNameTransformer($this->em);

        $builder
            ->add('activitiesNumber', 'choice', [
                'label' => 'Souhaitez-vous exercer une seconde activité ?',
                'expanded' => false,
                'choices' => array(
                    2 => 'Oui',
                    1 => 'Non',
                ),
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'radio-inline'
                ],
            ])
        ;

        $builder->get("activitiesNumber")->addEventSubscriber(new AddSecondaryActivityFieldsSubscriber());
    }
}
```

The Subscriber :

```
class AddSecondaryActivityFieldsSubscriber  implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA => 'postSetData',
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT => 'postSubmit',
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function postSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $activitiesNumber = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm()->getParent();

        if (2 == $activitiesNumber) {
            $this->addSecondaryActivityField($form);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function postSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $activitiesNumber = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm()->getParent();

        echo '<pre>';
        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($activitiesNumber);
        echo '</pre>';

        if (2 == $activitiesNumber) {
            $this->addSecondaryActivityField($form);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param FormInterface $form
     */
    public function addSecondaryActivityField(FormInterface $form)
    {
        $form
            ->add('secondaryActivity', 'text', [
                'label' => 'Activité secondaire souhaitée',
                'attr' => [
                    'required' => true,
                ],
            ]);
    }
}
```

In the postSubmit method, I dump the $activitiesNumber and instead of receiving a integer value (1 or 2), I receive the following array :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  bool(true)
  [1]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

This is just a de-indexed array of the radios, and I have no way to know which one was checked..

But if I change my activitiesNumber field to a select box ("expanded" => false), I receive an integer value (the value of the selected option).

I could fix the problem by using a select instead of radio button, but I really need radio button on this feature. Any one knows about this bug ? How can I solve it, or make this works ?

Comment: The one which was checked has `bool(true)`. In your case first radio was clicked thats why you have `0=>bool(true), 1=>bool(false)`. Try selecting second radio to see that 1 becomes `1=>bool(true)`.

Comment: that's the case. So I could guess which value was checked this way. But this looks over-complicated.. Is it some kind of bug related to radio buttons ? Is there a way to retrieve the indexed array of initial values (2 => "Oui ", 1 => "Non") in the subscriber ?